# How to run a content script inside a chrome-extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

We have a separate html page that can be access inside `chrome-extension://` and we want to run the content script inside that extension page, but it seems like the content script doesn't run inside it.

Even updated the `manifest.json` file to add `chrome-extension` domain but to no avail?

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*.pdf", "chrome-extension://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentPage.js", "polyfills.js", "runtime.js", "main.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
```

Note that we should only be running it inside our own content script, so i will also change the `chrome-extension://*/*` to `chrome-extension://{chromeId}/*`.

What should be the approach for this one?

Comment: Content scripts are for web pages by design. What you can do is write a devtools panel extension (example: Storage Area Explorer) that can access the currently open page of another extension, or use chrome.debugger API.

Comment: In case this chrome-extension:// page is from your own extension, just load the js file normally in the html file: `<script src=file.js></script>`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Got it. Loading the js files directly worked. thanks